# Android hint is hindering EditText validation

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I have 2 questions.

I have a few `EditText`s that have to be validated on a button click. I used everything to check if the edittexts are empty, but it always showed I have something in edittext and is not empty. I later removed the hint and it worked.

I tried `edittext.getText().toString().trim().length()==0`, `TextUtils.isEmpty(edittext.getText())`, `edittext.matches("")`, but nothing worked.

What should I do to check if the `EditText`is empty without removing the `android:hint="blah"`

2.And also, I'm trying to setError for the `editName,editPhNo`. But it's not displayed. It works for the `editPassword,editConfirmPassword`. Is there something wrong with my layout?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.prematixsofs.taxiapp.EditUserDetails">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
    <!--Display UserDetails Layout-->

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/displayLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phNo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/edit"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                android:text="Edit"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<!--Edit Layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/editLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPhNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter new Phone Number"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter new Password"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:password="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Confirm Password"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:password="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveOnEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
saveOnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText())&&TextUtils.isEmpty(phno.getText())&&TextUtils.isEmpty(editPassword.getText())&&TextUtils.isEmpty(editConfirmPassword.getText())) //Check if empty here
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter the details you want to update",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                if (validate()) {
                    if (editConfirmPassword.getText().toString().equals(editPassword.getText().toString())) {
                        databaseHelper.saveOnEdit(sessionManager.getUserEmail(), editName.getText().toString(), editPhNo.getText().toString(), editPassword.getText().toString().toString());
                        editName.setText("");
                        editConfirmPassword.setText("");
                        editPassword.setText("");
                        editPhNo.setText("");
                    } else {
                        editConfirmPassword.setError("Passwords don't match");
                        editPassword.setError("Passwords don't match");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords don't match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    phno.setError("Enter valid phone number");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a valid Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_user_details);
        edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        phno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phNo);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        editConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editConfirmPassword);
        editPhNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPhNo);
        userDetailList = new ArrayList();
        displayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        editLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editLayout);
        editLayout.setVisibility(editLayout.GONE);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        userDetailList = databaseHelper.displayUserDetails(sessionManager.getUserEmail());
        name.setText(userDetailList.get(0).toString());
        phno.setText(userDetailList.get(1).toString());
        email.setText(userDetailList.get(2).toString());
        displayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        editLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.editLayout);
        saveOnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveOnEdit);`

Comment: Post total code . Hope we will fix

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya. I've posted the code

Comment: Toast `Enter the details you want to update` not printing if empty ?

Comment: Yes, the toast does not occur even if it's empty. But if I remove the  `android:hint="blah"` the toast is displayed

Comment: very strange . for test case you just use String checking instead of `TextUtils`

Comment: i mean `name.getText().toString().length()==0`

Comment: I tried everything..like I mentioned in the question. If I remove the `android:hint`, it works and the `Toast` is displayed

Comment: Are you sure your `findViewById` calls are actually good? Hints shouldn't be returned by `getText()`, maybe you mistakenly assigned some `TextView` to your `EditText` fields (but you would need to have them declared as a `TextView`, otherwise `ClassCastException` would be thrown).

Can you paste the the method you assign your fields to Views returned from `findViewById`?

Comment: @MateuszHerych. I've posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit to the question, you are checking the wrong fields! `name` and `phno` are `TextView`. Change them to the actual `EditText` as shown below:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editName.getText())&&TextUtils.isEmpty(editPhNo.getText())&&TextUtils.isEmpty(editPassword.getText())&&TextUtils.isEmpty(editConfirmPassword.getText())) //Check if empty here
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter the details you want to update",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I want the `Toast` to be displayed only if all the `EditText`s  are empty

Comment: Hi. Thanks. That was it. Can you tell me why I cant `setError` for `editName, editPhNo`?

Comment: @Abhi, Same problem. The line `phno.setError("Enter valid phone number");` also uses the `TextView`, change it to `editPhNo`.